# If two electrons move up to a higher energy level in an atom, is it considered excited?

Tags: electronic-configuration

In Germanium, if two electrons go from 1s go to 4p is it in its excited state?

Answer (score 1):

http://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/Handbook/Tables/germaniumtable5.htm 
Energy levels of a neutral germanium atom 
https://www.webelements.com/germanium/orbital_properties.html 
Middle, electron binding energies for germanium

It will certainly be in one of its excited states, yes, probably followed by an Auger cascade.

```
Label   Orbital   eV 
K       1s       11103 
L I     2s       1414.6 
L II    2p1/2    1248.1 
L III   2p3/2    1217 
M I     3s       180.1 
M II    3p1/2    124.9 
M III   3p3/2    120.8 
M IV    3d3/2    29.8 
M V     3d5/2    29.2
```

Comment: i thought an atom can only become excited when only ONE electron moves to a higher energy level? so why does it get excited when two electrons move up?

Comment: "Excited" means "higher energy state". Everything higher than the ground state is therefore considered excited.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rydberg_atom  "A Rydberg atom is an excited atom with one or more electrons that have a very high principal quantum number,"

Comment: @Jonie: People commonly refer to such states as "doubly excited".